# Template as parameter in class

Tags: c++, templates

I have header file and in my header file I make a template and I want to use the template just on one function and not force all other functions.  Is it possible to get the type before the function like i did in `main`?
This is an example:

## TestTemp.h

```
// TestTemp.h
#ifndef _TESTTEMP_H_
#define _TESTTEMP_H_
template<class T>
class TestTemp  
{
public:
    TestTemp();
    void SetValue( int obj_i );
    int Getalue();
    void sum(T b, T a);

private:
    int m_Obj;
};
#include "TestTemp.cpp"

#endif
```

## TestTemp.cpp

```
//TestTemp.cpp
include<TestTemp.h>
TestTemp::TestTemp()
{
}
void TestTemp::SetValue( int obj_i )
{
    m_Obj = obj_i ;
}

int TestTemp::GetValue()
{
    return m_Obj ;
}

template<class T>
void TestTemp<T>::sum(T b, T a)
{
    T c;
    c = b + a;
}
```

## main.cpp

```
//main.cpp
include<TestTemp.h>
void main()
{
    TestTemp t;
    t.sum<int>(3,4);
}
```

Have any ideas?

Comment: your sum is not a template function!

Comment: so how i make it to be a template?

Comment: Never ever `#include` a cpp file from within a header!  Use your linker to combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TestTemp is a template class already, no need to make sum template function.

```
TestTemp<int> t;
t.sum(3, 4);
```

If you really want to make `sum` function a template function of `TestTemp`:

```
template<class T>
class TestTemp  
{
public:
    //....
    template<typename U>
    void sum(U b, U a);

private:
    int m_Obj;
};
```

To implement it outside template class:

```
template<class T>
template<typename U>
void TestTemp<T>::sum(U b, U a)
{
    T c;
    c = b + a;
}

int main()
{
    TestTemp<int> t;
    t.sum<int>(3, 4);
}
```

However, I feel you just need a free template function

```
template<typename T>
T sum(T a, T b)
{ return a + b; }
```

Comment: but i dont know if its int or something else until i use the function sum and i need to declare   TestTemp in the begin

Comment: TestTemp<> t;
t.sum(3, 4);  its fine??

Comment: TestTemp is a template, you haven't specialize it for any type yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
// TestTemp.h

#ifndef _TEST_TEMP_H_
#define _TEST_TEMP_H_

class TestTemp
{
public:
    TestTemp();
    void SetValue( int obj_i );
    int Getalue();

    template<class T>
    void sum(T b, T a);

private:
    int m_Obj;
};

TestTemp::TestTemp() {}

void TestTemp::SetValue( int obj_i )
{
   m_Obj = obj_i ;
}

int TestTemp::Getalue()
{
    return m_Obj ;
}

template<class T>
void TestTemp::sum(T b, T a)
{
   T c;
   c = b + a;
}

#endif

//main.cpp
#include <TestTemp.h>

int main()
{
    TestTemp t;
    t.sum<int>(3,4);
    return 0;
}
```

What you need is a normal class which has a template member function.

It's not a god idea to include an cpp file in header file. For template functions, just put it in header file.

Comment: error C2768:TestTemp::sum : illegal use of explicit template arguments

Comment: this what i get when i do this

Comment: @user3951910 It doesn't make any errors on g++ 4.8.3 with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11`. (just warning about unused variable `c`).. What is your compiler?

Comment: i work with visual studio 2010 with the default compiler i think it's vc++ 2010

Comment: @dor_torge It seems "template member function of non-template class" is a new feature in C++ 11. Code in my answer (above) works in MSVC 2013 and g++ 4.9.1. :) It's a feasible solution, but, unfortunately  doesn't work with old compiler T_T.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template). There are many examples.

I think it should work as you expect it if you just remove

```
template<class T>
```

from the

```
#ifndef _TESTTEMP_H_
#define _TESTTEMP_H_
--> template<class T> <--
class TestTemp
```

block. You don't have to define the whole class as templated when you just want a method to have template parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define TestTemp as normal class of which "sum" is a template function. Then in your function "main" (i.e. the caller), the template argument will be deduced from the function arguments.

```
class TestTemp
{
public:
    TestTemp();
    void SetValue(int obj_i);
    int Getalue();

    template<class T>
    void sum(T b, T a);

private:
    int m_Obj;
};

TestTemp::TestTemp() {}

void TestTemp::SetValue(int obj_i)
{
    m_Obj = obj_i;
}

int TestTemp::Getalue()
{
    return m_Obj;
}

template<class T>
void TestTemp::sum(T b, T a)
{
    T c;
    c = b + a;
}


//main.cpp


int main()
{
    TestTemp t;
    t.sum(3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```